# Changing Gridview row background color when editing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, colors

I'm having some trouble with editing a gridview row's background color when Editing it.

The thing is, I am using the `RowDataBound` event method to change `e.Row.BackColor` based on a criteria when displaying the report( 3 different colors depending on result ). For the rows that don't fall under that criteria, a GridView's property `<EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />` is applied upon clicking the Edit button.

However, I can't seem to find a way to change the color of those that do fall under the criteria since RowDataBound seems to be called all the time, overriding any changes I make.

Any suggestions?

Comment: RowDataBound  is only called when you DataBind your Gridview, but you dont need to bind it on every postback. You have to save your criterias somewhere(in Database or Viewstate). Then you can set the Backcolor in RowDataBound .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

write a single line in Grid RowEditing Event:

```
GridView1.EditRowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. Configure GridView row editing. This should be enough information. Let me know if you need some more.

```
protected void uxGrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    ClearBackColor();

    GridViewRow row = uxGrid.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
    row.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
} 

private void ClearBackColor()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in uxGrid.Rows)
    {
        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" >
    <Columns>
    </Columns>

    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />    
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#999999" /> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not write you own logic method to change rows back color?, loop through rows, this you can avoid the postback issue...maybe!

Answer (score 0):

As @Rami said create a method that loops through the DataGrid rows and change the color. Call this method in PreRender event handler. This way you are calling this method once every postback.